# Транскрипция слова " вообще"

Tags: транскрипция

Какая транскрипция у слова "вообще":

въʌпш̅ʼэ́ или вʌпш̅ʼэ́?

Answer (score 3):

въʌпш̅ʼэ́

Литературное произношение не допускает стяжения сочетаний гласных

Answer (score 1):

> Какая транскрипция у слова "вообще":
>
> **въʌпш̅ʼэ́** или **вʌпш̅ʼэ́**?

Допустимы оба варианта, но более предпочтительным в настоящее время считается, вроде бы,  **второй** из этих вариантов.

См. *«Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка» М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткина, Р. Ф. Касаткиной (М., 2012):*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]